# JS fadeIn, fadeOut troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pure CSS rollover that I'm trying to add a smooth transition/fade effect to and I can't seem to get it to go.

When you hover over the div "online", a new div "online-hover" appears. "Online" is the default with a background image, then the new div "online-hover" should fade in on top with a new background image. I have the HTML & CSS working, but now I'm trying to add JS to make it look pretty. Example:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="steps online">
<div class="steps-hover online-hover"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.steps{
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
width: 240px;
text-align: center;
height: 234px;
cursor: pointer;
 } 
.online{
background: url("images/applyonline.jpg") top left no-repeat;
}
.online-hover{
background: url("images/online-hover.jpg") top left no-repeat;
}
.steps-hover{
display: none;
}
div.online:hover div.online-hover {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 960px;
text-align: center;
height: 180px;
position: absolute; 
top: 234px;
display: block;
left: 0;
z-index: 3;
right: 0px;
cursor: auto;
}
```

And from following examples in other posts, I attempted the following JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{    
$("div.online").hover(
  function () {
    $("div.online-hover").fadeIn('slow');
  }, 
  function () {
    $("div.online-hover").fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
});​

</script>
```

But it's not working. What did I do wrong? I'm so not good at JS, so feel free to dummy it down for me!

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: Any error in the console? works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/c6gRp/

Comment: I didn't realize to look there. Says SyntaxError: illegal character


});​

index.html (line 110, col 3)

Comment: @PSL: Added .stop() for better usability: http://jsfiddle.net/c6gRp/2/. Also, make sure your divs have either a height specified or content in them!

Comment: I had copied the code and pasted it into my HTML, so it must have carried over some invisible characters. I just retyped the }); and the fade in works, but not the fade out.

Comment: @PSL what do I do with the .stop(). I suppose this is why the fade out is not working?

Comment: @user2574250 even if you dont have stop it should still work as seen in my original fiddle. issue was with the illegal char. adding a stop just improves the animation when you make random hovers.

Comment: @user2574250 why it worked for you copy pasting the fiddle was because i had removed it while preparing the fiddle initially and elliot added stop in the same fiddle you copy pasted it and worked. Animation doesnt need stop() to work, it is only required when you make frequent animations before one is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an illegal char at the end of document ready closing braces remove it. It is better seen in **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDzxt/)**.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
$("div.online").hover(
  function () {
    $("div.online-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeIn('slow');
  }, 
  function () {
    $("div.online-hover").stop(true, true, true).fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
});​ //<-- here
```

Also use `.stop()` to prevent any previous queued up animation from running and changing the normal behavior when you make frequent hovers.

Comment: I'd only suggest adding .stop() before fadeIn() or fadeOut().

Comment: Hmm the .stop() seems to have messed up the fade in. Sometimes it works when I hover, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @user2574250 Your real issue was the illegal char, not `stop()` probably would have come through when you copy pasted the section from some other file or a page.

Comment: Well I must have been hovering too quickly, fade in works, but it still isn't fading out.

Comment: @user2574250 use ` $("div.online-hover").stop(true, true, true)` it will take care of frequent hovers. See this http://jsfiddle.net/SJwAx/ . Doing just stop() is not enough.

Comment: That seems better! Any idea why it's not fading out?

Comment: @user2574250 it is fading out in the fiddle. Something with your code?

Comment: I see that, argh. I don't see any errors and I retyped the code in case there were more invisible characters. As soon as my cursor leaves the div "online", the "online-hover" image abruptly disappears. It should fade back to the default, correct? Would it have to be in my JS code, or could there be a problem somewhere else?

Comment: I copy my code from Sublime text and paste it in jsFiddle and it's working fine. But not in Firefox. ARGH.

Comment: OK I see my problem. I was trying a diff block than the one I posted in the example and something in my CSS is goofing it up. On the right track though. Thanks!